# How to switch to root in Jenkins docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have setup Jenkins server inside a docker container. The image I am using is `docker pull jenkins`. After that I connect to the container by `docker exec -it b74d035352ec bash`.  The default user is `jenkins` but I can't switch to root and got below errors:

```
jenkins@b74d035352ec:/$ su -
su: must be run from a terminal
```

I got below error when running `sudo`:

```
$ sudo ls

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Does anyone know how to solve the issue? I do need root permission on that container. Or should I install anything? I can build a new image from this image if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only do that during build time, as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#installing-more-tools).

```
FROM jenkins
# if we want to install via apt
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ruby make more-thing-here
# drop back to the regular jenkins user - good practice
USER jenkins
```

So you have to build your own image to execute tasks as *root* user.

Answer (score 6):

Simply you can login to the root account of the running jenkins-container as

```
 docker exec -u 0 -it <container_id/container_name> /bin/bash
```

After logged in as root, you can switch to the jenkins account using `su - jenkins` if needed.